# SQL Coalesce not returning any rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using Postgres and have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM "osmlocal-dsd-de".t_osm_vehicle_image t 
WHERE t.vehicle_config_id = 3 
  and image_type_id = 2
```

Which returns one row:

```
id  vehicle_config_id       cosy_url       image_type_id
113         3               SomeValue             2
```

When I run the following:

```
SELECT * from "osmlocal-dsd-de".t_osm_vehicle_image t 
WHERE t.vehicle_config_id = 3 
  and image_type_id = 2 
  and coalesce(t.cosy_url, '') = ''
```

Zero rows are returned.

I think my understanding of `coalesce` is wrong, because I would have expected one row still to be returned, because the `cosy_url` is not `null`.

Any advise on what I am doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding of coalesce is wrong

It returns the first argument that is not null. If all arguments are null, the COALESCE function will return null

In your case `t.cosy_url` is not null it is equally `SomeValue` and your condition doesn't work because `SomeValue` is not equal `''`

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be misunderstanding `coalesce()`.  It returns the first value that is not `null`.

In your case, you have:

```
coalesce(t.cosy_url, '')
```

Because t.cosy_url has a value (`'SomeValue'`), this evaluates to that value.  The value is not `''` so the expression returns false and the entire `where` clause returns false.

If you want non-`NULL` values, then use:

```
t.cosy_url is not null
```